# Re-rendering a component with useSpring resets animation chain and over time makes other animations staggery

Tags: reactjs, performance, animation, react-spring

I have this spring defining a looped animation:

```
const style = useSpring({
    from: { marginBottom: 0 },
    to: [
      { marginBottom: 0 },
      { marginBottom: 80, config: { duration: 600 }, delay: 3000 },
      { marginBottom: -80, config: { duration: 0 } },
      { marginBottom: 0, config: { duration: 600, delay: 1000 } },
    ],
    loop: true,
  })
```

My problem is that whenever I re-render the component containing the spring, the animation 'resets' and starts moving towards the first `to` position (in this case `{ martinBottom: 0 }`)

- It can be seen in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-ully-0yooqc?file=/src/App.tsx) - click the 'reset' button just as the arrow is traveling up and it will reverse course instantly
- The documentation [also hints that](https://react-spring.io/hooks/use-spring#and-this-is-how-you-create-a-chain) stabilizing the references of `from` and `to` may solve the issue... and it kind of does, but it introduces a new one: if the components re-renders shortly before the animation starts, it skips the 'travel up' portion: [sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stable-reference-0nexur?file=/src/App.tsx).

The bigger problem is that the more times I 'interrupt' the animation cycle by re-rendering, the more it affects some of my other, more demanding animations, making them more and more staggered.

- Refreshing whole app instantly resets this decay and makes all animations fluid again. When I remove this `useSpring` from my code, this decay disappears

So what is going on there? Is there something I'm missing?

From [this docs example](https://react-spring.io/hooks/use-spring#either-overwrite-values-to-change-the-animation), It makes sense to me that the animation resets on re-render ... but then why does [this example](https://react-spring.io/hooks/use-spring#either-overwrite-values-to-change-the-animation) instruct me to compose staged animations this way, am I missing some key step?

And what's up with this slow 'decay' of other animations' performance, is that a known cause to that?

Comment: A note about the "staggering": It seems to only happen on some machines/in some environmnents. My colleague tried on his M1 Macbook in Safari and it did not happen for him. I have not pinned down what causes it. I simply decided to avoid such Spring animation loops alltogether, and use standard css transitions when I can.